# synchronous boost converter design

Tags: boost, synchronous

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnTiC1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Does anybody there has an ideea about how to make a synchronous boost converter only with N channel mosfets? I intend to do one, but the single design I know is the one with an N channel and a P channel mosfet (like in the attached image).

Comment: The PMOS in your schematic is wrong-way-around. When the NMOS is active, the body diode of the PMOS will connect the load back to the NMOS drain.

Comment: Thank you! That is a good observation. I did not noticed that mistake when I posted the circuit.

Comment: What about connecting the transistor at the negative side of the circuit instead of the positive side? I have no Idea if that would actually work.

Comment: I think that won't work very well because the circuit will miss a common ground. Form my knowledge this should be always the case in every circuit that doesn't need galvanic isolation.

Answer (score 1):

You can but it would be a tricky design, since you would have to drive the gate of N channel mosfet that replace the p channel one, even higher than the boost voltage you are creating in order to turn it off fully. So It would require some complicated drive circuitry as compared to the P channel solution.

Comment: Be aware, though, that this kind of boosted gate drive circuit is a common feature on IC regulators and regulator controllers.

Comment: Very true, additionally bootstrap gate drive will might your max duty cycle and you max voltage output

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But does anybody has an ideea about a specific, well working design?